# to_date with regex in postgresql

Tags: sql, string, postgresql, date, sql-update

I've got a column of varchar type, it contains dates in the format of `8-Jun-12` and `18-Jun-12`

I have an empty column of date type

I'd like to fill up my column with the dates as actual dates.
I was hoping to get away with something like:

```
SET formatted_date=to_date(mydatecol, ('[0-9]{1,2}-[a-zA-Z]{3}-[0-9]{2}'));
```

But my resulting column is null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `to_date()`:

```
update mytable
set formatted_date = to_date(mystring, 'dd-mon-yy')
```

Comment: oh man I feel so dumb, thanks. 11 mins and I can accept the answer

Answer (score 0):

PostgreSQL?

You can just hard-cast it:

```
WITH 
inp(dts) AS (
          SELECT '8-Jun-12'
UNION ALL SELECT '18-Jun-12'
)
SELECT
  dts
, dts::DATE 
FROM inp;
-- out     dts    |    dts     
-- out -----------+------------
-- out  8-Jun-12  | 2012-06-08
-- out  18-Jun-12 | 2012-06-18
```